# Router creation in API, SP response

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I'm starting to develop an API but I don't have a high level of programming. I am occupying express and node.js. I am trying to add the response of the call to the SQL_SP_STATUS to a Router, in order to get its results after a call:

```
var connectionStatus = async function (stpName = process.env.SQL_SP_STATUS) {
const response = await sqlDB.getStatus(dbSQL,stpName);
return response;
```

}

When trying to make the Router from some examples that I have, it does not work, I have set it up as follows:

```
router.get('/test', async function () {
    stpName = process.env.SQL_SP_STATUS;
    let connectionStatus = stpName ;
    const response = await sqlDB.getStatus(dbSQL,stpName);
    return response;
});
```

The truth is that I do not know the correct way to do it, please I need advice.

Thank you very much in advance, I will be attentive to your answers.

Regards!

Comment: Are you using node and express for this? If so, you're supposed to do a) `async function (req, res)` and b) `res.send(response);` instead of returning it.

Comment: Look at the [hello world example here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) and fix your `/test` route accordingly. Post any error messages you're getting. Your question is two rolled into one: creating a working express route and querying your DB for some status. These two problems are unrelated, so please clarify what exactly you're asking about and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris I'm studying your comments Greetings thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to do it. You can have your routes defined e.g.

```
    testroute.js
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.json({});
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

Have a router file that includes all your routes.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/api/test', require('./routes/testroute'));

module.exports = router;
```

and maybe in your express file have something like

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(require('./routes'));
```

Read the documentation for better understanding.
[express documentation](https://expressjs.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @ kg99, I am taking notes of what you mention, but I do not understand how I should make the call to the SP